# VueJS: How to navigate to a different route from global JS function

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I have a Vue.js app where a have a link tag that is not rendered by Vue, and I cannot add the runtime compiler to my bundle.

The link tag will point to a valid route that has been registered with Vue Router.  I'd like to be able to soft navigate to the route (basically the same behaviour as `<router-link />`) when the link is clicked.

Currently clicking the link causes a hard page refresh.  Is there a way of accessing the router globally?  My app is compiled using webpack.  The `Vue` instance is not currently available on the `window`, and I'd prefer not to expose it if possible.

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Probably the best approach is to register a `hook` on the `window` object and use that so you can navigate from inside Vue.

Something like this:

```
//inside main.js or any other vue component that can get a reference to router
window.vueRouterHook = (path) => {
 router.push(path)
}
```

After this is executed you should be able to access `vueRouterHook` from any JS script like this

```
window.vueRouterHook('my path')
```

You can, of course, add params to the method if you want.